# 'Build' is not displayed in iTunes Connect using Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, build-version

I also get the same problem while uploading my build to the app store via Xcode 8. After uploading successfully from Xcode, I login to iTunes connect and see that it shows as Processing. After a little while it disappears. I've tried multiple times but have never been able to make it visible.

I emailed Apple Support and they only say that my build contains an error and they ask me to check my build settings again. But, If there is any error there, shouldn't it at least be showing something for me to know?

How have others resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your email inbox. This may be the issue:

> Dear developer,
>
> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "App Name". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
>
> - Missing required icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0.
> - Missing required icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions supporting iPad Pro.
> - Missing required icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. after 8th attempt i tried Xcode Version 8.1 beta (8T29o) and also updated all my pods to most recent version. now it works for me, but not sure about the exact problem.

Comment: It might be because of the bug of xCode 8 and Apple released new version to fix this issue. Let me try and see how :) . Thank you for your advice

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567555/new-build-disappears-after-uploading-it-to-itunes-connect

Comment: Finally I resolved the issue by adding Photo Usage Description in my plist :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was receiving the warning email from iTunes connect [It's warning not error] but still it was not showing under TestFlight 
After resolving warning it gets available

[image: Ref warning image][image: Itunesconnect]